# Unable to download Git plugin from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to download GIT plugin via URL : https://github.com/OSAMES/ionic-Select-Control.git

in Visual Studio 2015 (update 2 ) I opened config.xml (in designer), then in Plugins section, I clicked on Custom and selected Git option. Entered above URL and clicked Arrow button.

However, it is giving error as "Plugin download failed from URL: https://github.com/OSAMES/ionic-Select-Control.git"

The URL works in browser.

Any idea? There can't be proxy issue with VS 2015 update 2 as I was able to download another plugin yesterday.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested at the moment and I have not encountered any problem with `bower install ionic-select-control --save`

Have you made a `npm init` before launch bower ?

In fact this plugins is for Ionic not for Cordova and need also angularjs.
I do not think it is possible to adapt to Cordova.
The only solution would be to develop a specific plugin for Cordova.

**Edit**: I test on new Cordova project in vs2015U2. My solution if you not use command line is to edit bower.json, add *ionic-select-control* dependencies
[image: add ionic-select-control]
[image: Visual Studio proposed version by request on github]

and after in solution explorer, right click on dependencies and click *restore packages* in menu.
[image: Updated dependencys]

VisualStudio 2015 request npm.org to fill intelisence for auto completing and find packages names

Comment: Have you made a npm init before launch bower? No I am not aware of it. is it a command?

Comment: What is the difference between editing bower.json and manually adding required files? I downloaded the Git content, then added JS and css files to respective folder, then added reference in index.html file and it started working. However, am I loosing something if I do not install from bower? Further, while editing in bower.json file it is not giving me any version choice. It shows *.

Comment: _npm init_ is a command from nodejs.

Bower is here for helping to maintain version. With a bower update, all your packages is updated. 

You can also use your method but else you are responsible of updating the packages yourself.

You can take time to learn bower and npm because bower take components and place it in bower_component folder. After, you need to pickup everywhere js, css, font, ect... from this folder to include in your www folder.

I use a gulp script to extract everything I need installed packages from bower.

Comment: For intellisense, I do not know. You can always ask on the VisualStudio forum

Answer (score 1):

You can install it by ID, like ionic-select-control.

But it is not a Cordova plugin, so just install it with bower. This window is for installing Cordova plugins only.

Comment: With ID VS gives error as "This ID maps to a plugin tht is not Cordova specific. Please enter and ID for a Cordova plugin with a valid plugin.xml in the project root."

Comment: With Bower, I am getting retry error like "Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ionic-select-control failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 1.7s" after 5 retry it is saying that tunneling sokcket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8080 8080:80"

Comment: Is there anyway to install it locally (after downloading from Git)?

Comment: Do you have a bower.json file at root of yout VS project? If so, open a command-line to the root of your project and type:

bower install ionic-select-control --save

Comment: @barbara.post I am getting this error by exactly doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by adding .bowerrcc file to my solution. The file was added and edited to have proxy configuration. For example:

```js
{
  "directory": "www/lib",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
  "proxy"       : "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080",
  "https-proxy" : "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080",
  "strict-ssl"  : false
}
```